# Converting bstr_t to double

Tags: c++, double, bstr

How to do the transform bstr_t to double in c++?

I was thinking to convert to *char, then *char to double?

Comment: What is a `bstr_t`? Post code and/or decode the type into C++ primitive types.

Comment: It's an RAII wrapper class for a COM `BSTR` (which is a pointer to wide char with special semantics, basically)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: It's a Windows-specific [C++ reference counting wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx) for the Windows-specific [`BSTR` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b2d7d2c-47af-4389-a6b6-b01b7e915228(VS.85)), which stands for "basic string". It's essentially a doubly-null-terminated Unicode string that has a 4-byte length prefix.

Comment: It is _bstr_t.  Cast to const wchar_t* to avoid it doing all this unnecessary work.  Then wcstod().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `char*` or `wchar_t*` string, use the [`strtod`/`wcstod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) functions to read a double.

E.g. using @Steve's suggestion:

```
_bstr_t x;
double q = wcstod(x, NULL); // implicit conversion!
double p = strtod(x, NULL); // same
```

Apparently `_bstr_t` has implicit conversion operators both to `const char *` and `const wchar_t*`, so you can use them directly in the float parsing functions.

Comment: Note that the conversion to char * invokes [ConvertBSTRToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewezf1f6(v=VS.100).aspx) which allocates memory so it is relatively expensive (although the result is cached).  Conversion to wchar_t* is inexpensive since BSTR is basically a wide char anyway.

Comment: Frank: Good to know. So prefer the `wcstod` version :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can cast to `const char*` (there is a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btdzb8eb.aspx) for this that handles mapping from wide char to MBCS under the covers) and then convert to double as you wish - [stringstream::operator>>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whtx1k1x.aspx) for example

Answer (score 2):

Call [wcstod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab.aspx) or _wcstod_l if you want to control locale.

```
bstr_t myBstr_t = L"1.234";

double d = wcstod(myBstr_t, NULL);
```